# How to fix "Easy Soap Request" not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, soap, axios

easy-soap-request package kept on sending me an error like "axios is not a function" which has something to do with the package itself.

I tried to import the axios package inside the easy-soap-request package but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Example Usage `Node.js` from [easy-soap-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request) works for me.

I ran it on Windows 11.

The axios version installed 1.4.0. it's dependency of easy-soap-request.

I copy from package-lock.json

Here is what  I test example
Save as 'demo.js`. I copied it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request)

```js
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const fs = require('fs');

// example data
const url = 'https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php';
const sampleHeaders = {
  'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'soapAction': 'https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl#LatLonListZipCode',
};
const xml = fs.readFileSync('test/zip-code-envelope.xml', 'utf-8');

// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: xml, timeout: 1000 }); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
  const { headers, body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(headers);
  console.log(body);
  console.log(statusCode);
})();
```

```json
    "node_modules/easy-soap-request": {
      "version": "5.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/easy-soap-request/-/easy-soap-request-5.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-p06gAo5VsCPk3zkPy7iUsRqxW0SfsU4fi/KxxlKZ/J+ASfl27qpmxrH4+ALPTR8sECS+BPYFEJPzYY6Y6eK2mQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0"
      }
    },
```

It needs this `zip-code-envelope.xml` file from [here](https://github.com/circa10a/easy-soap-request/tree/main/test)
It needs to place `./test/` sub directory.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ndf="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ndf:LatLonListZipCode soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <zipCodeList xsi:type="dwml:zipCodeListType" xmlns:dwml="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">75001</zipCodeList>
      </ndf:LatLonListZipCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

#### Install dependencies

```
npm install easy-soap-request fs
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Confirm by Soap UI 5.7.0

#### WSDL URL

```
https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl
```

#### function list

[image]

#### Same function call as same as `demo.js`

```
LatLonListZipCode
```

[image]

#### Result in SOAP UI

[image]

#### Conclusion

The `easy-soap-request` example demo is fine so your dependencies or PC is something wrong.